# Core Data Inheritance entities not being saved

Tags: swift, inheritance, core-data

I have the following Data Model in Core Data:
[image]

*Note: I Setup `Attachment` to be `Abstract` and `ExpenseAttachment` and `LeaveAttachment` have their parent set as `Attachment`

When I try to save `ExpenseAttachment` or `LeaveAttachment`, I run intro the problem that the code to save a new attachment runs fine with no errors, but nothing really happens, since when I try to retrieve it there are no records.

So I use this code so save:

```
func syncExpenseAttachments(attachmentResponse: AttachmentResponse, expenseID: Int64)
{
    let backgroundContext : NSManagedObjectContext! = DataController.sharedInstance().backgroundContext

    backgroundContext.perform
    {
        let attachmentExpense = try? backgroundContext.fetch(Expense.fetchRequest()).filter { $0.tkID == expenseID }

        let attachment = ExpenseAttachment(context: backgroundContext)
        attachment.tkID = Int64(attachmentResponse.id ?? 0)
        attachment.createdDate = attachmentResponse.createdDate ?? Date()
        attachment.name = attachmentResponse.name ?? ""
        attachment.flaggedForDelete = false
        attachment.data = attachmentResponse.data as Data? ?? nil

        if let attachmentExpense = attachmentExpense {
            attachment.expense = attachmentExpense[0]
        }

        try? backgroundContext.save()

    }
}
```

And this code to get the records:

```
let attachmentRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ExpenseAttachment")
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: false)
attachmentRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

do {
    let coreDataExpenseAttachments = try DataController.sharedInstance().viewContext.fetch(attachmentRequest) as! [ExpenseAttachment]

    //Do some work

} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

After the save, trying to retrieve attachments returns nothing. However if I simply use the `Attachment` entity with saving, I can actually see records when I also try to retrieve data for the attachments enitity. I though you do not create or save the Abstract Parent Entity, just the Child Entities?

Comment: Could it be a problem that you have no attributes in your subclasses, only relationships? Also, have you made sure the Expense fetch returns something?

Comment: But isn't that the purpose of the inheritance? That I don't need to add the properties again. Tested the expense fetch and it's working :)

Comment: Of course. I was more thinking that this was some kind of issue with Core Data so that it didn't work properly with only a relationship in the inherited entity. Maybe you could add some dummy attribute, with a default value perhaps, to one of the sub-entities just to test if it works to save properly then?

Comment: Aah makes sense, I'll have to try that.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have exact same issue?

Comment: Actually for me it seems to be data related .. so never mind